# How can I clean this code without a lot of <a> tags respecting HTML semantic?

Tags: java, html, eclipse, w3c-validation

I'm trying to get rid of this code's warnings, but avoiding an excessive use of `<a>` tags. Eclipse shows a warning saying "*Invalid location of tag `<div>`.

Is it possible to to avoid this error in this JSP using Eclipse, respecting the required W3C HTML semantic request?

See the Eclipse warnings

- http://imageshack.com/a/img907/4755/TYhL7x.png
- http://imageshack.com/a/img537/2847/HjHvUA.png

  ```
  <a href="sonho.jsp">
  <div class="img">
      <img src="img/no-image.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="title">
      <h4><%= sonho.getTituloSonho() %></h4>
      <p><%= sonho.getDescricaoSonho() %></p>
      <% UsuarioBEANS usuario = usuarioBO.selecionarUsuario(sonho.getCdUsuario()); %>
      <p><strong><%= usuario.getNome() %></strong></p>
      <% CategoriaSonhoBEANS categoria = categoriaSonhoBO.obterCategoria(sonho.getCdCategoria()); %>
      <p class="status"><%= categoria.getNomeCategoria() %></p>
  </div>
  ```

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. What do you mean "clean this code"? what is the problem with a-tags? Can you show us what it would be like *with* a-tags, then tell us why you don't like it?

Comment: Agreed with @TarynEast.
Show us what it looks with with a-tags.

Also, the current structure you have in place is semantically in-correct - You have block elements being wrapped by inline elements, eg. <a href=""><p></p></a>

Comment: @thePav Apparently it's ok to wrap block-level elements in a-tags now...
http://html5doctor.com/block-level-links-in-html-5/
(I had to go check myself)

Comment: Thank you guys. So sorry, I did not explain myself very well. I improved the question and add some imagens. My goal is correct the Warning showed by Eclipse, but mainly to understand why. Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `<span style="display:box">` instead of `div`s. They will look the same and the warnings will probably go away.